# Dynamically create function calls

Tags: angularjs

I have a table populated with data from an API based on a user input.

I then display the results as follows:

```
<tr ng-repeat="show in data.popularMatches">
    <td><a href="#" ng-click="selectShow('{{show.id}}')">{{show.title}}</a></td>
    <td>{{show.title_description}}</td>
</tr>
```

What I am trying to achieve, is to pass the ID of each show to the `selectShow` function in my Angular controller when each show's link is clicked. How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should only need to have ng-click="selectShow(show.id)"